# Go TLS handshake error

Tags: ssl, go

So everything seems to be working fine on my webserver. But I randomly get

> http: TLS handshake error from IP EOF

The certs are all good. HTTPS connection works fine on mobile and desktop but I randomly get this error messages. Shouls I be worried or maybe its some bot with no https support?

The server is just a regular ListenAndServeTLS with an httprouter passed with the cert and key files. No error returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually nothing to worry about. This can simply be some network scanner which just tries to find out if somebody is listening on the port or some client with bad connectivity. As long as you don't get any problem reports from real clients you can just ignore this noise.